# How to resolve this environment variable not working issue

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, mern

I've been creating a website with the help of MERN stack and after creating the backend which works perfectly fine it connected to the database and all i created the frontend and tried to run both of them concurrently but I've been getting this error whenever i tried to do that

mongooseerror: the `uri` parameter to `openuri()` must be a string, got "undefined". make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createconnection()` is a string.

on further checking when i replaced the `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)` with the URI the connection works just fine. what should i do?

I am not able to connect to the database and the site shows Network connection error. I imported all the packages in the backend outside the file and that didn't work too. It's my first time working on this thing and i was able to solve a few errors.

I'll add the server.js code with this

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");
const productRoute = require("./routes/productRoute");
const contactRoute = require("./routes/contactRoute");
const errorHandler = require("./middleWare/errorMiddleWare");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const path = require("path");
    
const app = express();

//Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials: true
}));

app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")))

//Routes Middleware
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
app.use("/api/contactus", contactRoute);

//Routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Home Page");
});

//Error Middleware
app.use(errorHandler);

//connect to DB and start Server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('Server running on port ' + PORT);
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
```

Comment: First check `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI)`.  If that is `undefined`, then you just don't have the environment variable set properly before you run your process.

Comment: I see you also have the package `dotenv` in your project.  Are you using that to set environment variables?  If so, show us the `.env` file you're using.

Comment: thank you guys for the help. I tried things as u said and the env file was inside the backend folder was the reason why it didn't connect and gave the undefined value